# how to set value to input field in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <va-input label="Address 1"
        v-model="Address1"
        id="address"
        class="inp">
    </va-input>
</div>
```

below i am calling api to get data. after getting i need to set value to above input field.

```
document.getElementById("address").value =res.data[0].address1,
```

but the above code is not working.

Comment: this is not an vuejs way.

Comment: Change the model value `Address1` and not by directly manipulating dom. Ex: `this.Address1 = res.data[0].address1`

Comment: Pavan, do you have the Address1 variabled in the `data` field?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `ref` property, see here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref
Basically would look something like:

```
    <va-input label="Address 1"
              v-model="Address1"
              id="address"
              class="inp"
              ref="inputRef"
    >
         </va-input>
    ...
    this.$refs.inputRef.$el.value = ...
```

You may need to dig a little into the structure but from the `$el` you can access the element.

Comment: console log the `$el` and see exactly where you are, then target the child element you need

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this data to the "data" of the component,
just create :

```
`data() {
    return {
        Address1: ''
    }
}`
```

and at the `created()` or anywhere you want to assign this value : 
`this.Adress1 = res.data[0].address1`

Basically this is the vue way of doing these kind of things,and using the v-model properly.