# How to reset the input field based on the ref/id in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
 <button
                            class="verify-button-otp pxy_0"
                            :disabled="activationKey.length < 4"
                            @click="verifyOtp"
                            id="verifybtn"
                          >
                            VERIFY
                          </button>
```

```js
 resetNow() {
 
 //:ref="`input-${i}`" want to take ref from the input and want to reset the value
 
 input:'';
 
 }
```

```html
 <b-button class="button-self" v-on:click="resetNow" v-b-modal.modal1>GETIN</b-button> 
 
 <input
                              type="number" 
                              v-for="(key, i) in activationKeyFields"
                              :key="i"
                              :data-length="key.length"
                              :data-index="i"
                              :ref="`input-${i}`"
                              v-model="key.value"
                              @input="handleActivationInput($event)"
                              placeholder="-"
                              maxlength="1"
                              
                            />
                            <div class="activationkey dn" >
                             {{ activationKey }}
                            </div>
```

I want to reset the value for the input, i am thinking that we can do it by using the reference from the input and pass it to the reset method, I am attaching my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the ref, then call the element, and change it's value.

```js
resetNow(id){
    this.$refs[`input-${id}`].input.value = ""; //You may need to use .$el.value instead of .input.value
}
```

You will need to change your button to also pass the id number

```
v-on:click="resetNow(id)"
```

However, **this is not a good way of accomplishing this**. What you should be doing is resetting it's value via the variable referenced in `v-model` on the input tag.

e.g.

```js
resetNow(id){
    this.items[id].value = '';
}
```

I have created a codepen showing how to properly reset the fields here: https://codepen.io/pilotkid2011/pen/zYNpvPL

See also: [how to set value to input field in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59405427/2073738)

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above code, But the issue is,  after replacing with  the  above code, input values are not resetting. Technically your code is correct i agree,But i dont know why its not resetting

Comment: Howdy, are you getting any errors in the console? Also, you really should be resetting via the variable in v-model, as seen in the second half of my answer :)

Comment: No, I am not getting any console error, But  after giving this line this.items[id].value = '';

My other input value i.e, (mobile input) getting disabled.(after value reset only that mobile field will be un disable)

Comment: I have updated my verify button code also, because for the input field i am taking (activationKey as a reference value and passing it to the verify button, to check the length and proceed)

Comment: So in this case i am thinking to reset value based on """activationKey??

Comment: Why not set key.value=“” in the reset method? If not can you create a code sandbox so I can actually see what is going on?

Comment: Got it. here is my codepen for that

 https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/LYxOoWO

Comment: For that i need to add reset method to reset the fields.

Comment: This works, by using reactivity instead of accessing the refs to reset the field values
```resetNow() {       
       for(let i=0; i < this.activationKeyFields.length; i++){
         this.activationKeyFields[0].value = "";
       }
```

Comment: Yup it's working, But this time, it is resetting only 1st value. But how to reset all the 4 values

Comment: Please see: https://codepen.io/pilotkid2011/pen/zYNpvPL